# how to make an Android app to work in sync with a Web app

Tags: php, android, android-networking

I am new to android development and i am willing to make an Android app for Managing Notes and Task as well as i want to make a Web app for the same using PHP.(For learning purpose like Google Keep).I want both of this web app and android app to work in sync with each other, Just like Google's Google Keep works on Android and Web as well. what would be the easiest way to do this?
 Is it necessary to create a REST api for my web app so that my android app can query the web app ? 
Also i saw somewhere on internet that i should save all my data in Mysql Database on server and my Android app should retrieve all the data from the server but i if will do this then my app will not be work in offline mode. 
Please help, Thankyou .

Answer (score 1):

Yes,You should have a main Database on server and your Android app should retrieve all the data from the server,then Save them in your local database in android that can be same as or lesser than your main database.
Now you can work offline ,and when data has changed in your app ,you should keep them somewhere and sync them with your server database as soon as you got online.
and also you can use push Notification to notify your app that some data has been changed and no longer valid and application should update itself.
It's my idea Hope help you

Comment: how can i do that what techniques i should use ?